# How do I tab out of Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

At least since the Heart of the Swarm update I can't seem to find any key combination that lets me temporarily get out to Windows to check chats and so on. Is there a known combination or some tool I could use?

I tried using ctrl+alt+del and that allowed me to start the task manager but then HotS just popped to the front again.

Comment: I believe you have to enable Alt+Tab in the options menu.

Answer (score 2):

As Decency has pointed out there is a checkbox in "Option"-"Controls" at the top right under the header "Keyboard" that says "Disable Alt-Tab Shortcut" which you have to uncheck.
There is also one for "Disable Windows Key".

Note: If you uncheck this you don't have to change the graphics mode to "Windowed (Fullscreen)".

Comment: You don't need to change the graphics mode to Windowed, however if you do it speeds up the transition between SC2 and Windows

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

- **1. [Alt] + [Tab] (hold down [Alt] and press [Tab])**
- **2. [Windows key] if you have one. (Your taskbar will apear)**
- *3. Last, use the function you wrote yourself (though it does not seem to work for you)*

Comment: Windows key + ESC is another one, I would add.